# Installer with Python tools for Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-2.7, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I want to know how I can create a installer from python, I use Python Tools for Visual Studio, and I need a installer to finish my project, I would prefer to create the installer with Visual Studio, but this isn't essential, thanks.

- I use Python 2.7 and visual studio 2013 with python tools for visual
  studio